# What causes preventDefault to let the original event through

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I don't have an example at hand, but in some situations calling `event.preventDefault()` lets the original event through (navigating to page, submitting form etc) but returning false helps. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have an example to hand? OK, let me invent one that may or may not be whatever it was you were thinking of.

Remember that `return false;` is the equivalent of calling both `event.preventDefault();` and [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.stopPropagation). **EDIT: This applies with jQuery**, which explictly implements this behaviour and also normalises `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` for use in all browsers. It doesn't work that way in all browsers with "plain" JS, in fact older IE versions don't support `event.preventDefault()` at all, they have their own equivalent `event.returnValue = false;`

If you have nested elements and you handle the same event in several levels then calling `event.preventDefault()` will not stop the outer elements' event handlers from running, but `return false` will because it stops propagation of the event.

An example that demonstrates it: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/KjLv3/

```
<a href="#"><span>Click me to see an alert</span></a>

// using jQuery for simplicity in the example:

$("a span").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("a").click(function() {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

The alert will display. If you change the "a span" handler to return false the alert will not display.

Comment: So when `preventDefault` stops 'suddenly' from working, it's a sign that there is a deeper problem somewhere?

Comment: Could be, could be. But (as per my edit) with "plain" JS, different browsers (or versions of browsers - think IE) don't necessarily behave the same way. If you have a more specific problem at some stage you should post a question about that showing the problem code.

Comment: Mostly using the same browser. And it's a problem that keeps popping up 'occasionally', but what disturbed me was that I had no idea what might cause it and whether it was a sign of something worse

Answer (score 1):

**event.preventDefault()** prevents the browser from performing the default action (  if the event is cancelable ) without stopping further propagation of the event, whereas
**return false** prevents the event from propagating (or "bubbling up") the DOM, along with preventing the default action.

So,

```
function() {
  return false;
}
```

// IS EQUAL TO

```
function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```